# Different language code for Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3 migarion

Tags: multistore, magento2-migration-tool, language, data-migration, translation-dictionaries

I have a multi store in my magento 1.9 and i successfully migrated to Magento 2.3.4

one of my stores have language code and store code set to `zn_HK` in my Magento 1.9 , but in Magento 2.3.4 there is no more `zn_HK` language code for the locale configuration, so i changed it to `zh_Hant_HK`

then i tried to create a csv for one of the module like this:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/zh_Hant_HK.csv**

```
"original","翻譯"
```

but when i switch the store, the language didn't change

and when i change to production mode i got this error:

```
zh_HK argument has invalid value, run info:language:list for list of available locales
```

should i change my store code to `zh_Hant_HK` or did i miss something else?

Answer (score 0):

yes you should change that [csv name](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/455ca54f5479cedf00d4d10b8a6289a72eaab784/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/Config.php#L104) and probably you might want to put that translation file into (assuming you may have a custom theme as well) `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/zh_Hant_HK.csv`